# Moving my ViewModelBase to Portable Class Library

Tags: wpf, portable-class-library

I'm in the process of trying to use Portable Class Libraries to reduce my assembly per platform for my own MVVM framework.

So I currently have this code (inspired by @lbugnion MVVMLight)

```
        public static bool IsInDesignModeStatic
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_isInDesignMode.HasValue)
            {
```

#if SILVERLIGHT

```
                        _isInDesignMode = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool;
```

#else

```
                var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
                _isInDesignMode
                    = (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                                 .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                                 .Metadata.DefaultValue;

                // Just to be sure
                if (!_isInDesignMode.Value
                    && Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.StartsWith("devenv", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    _isInDesignMode = true;
                }
```

#endif

```
            }

            return _isInDesignMode.Value;
        }
    }

}
```

But when I try to use this inside PCL it doesn't recognize DesignerProperties and FrameworkElement, etc.
How should I overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like I do in the MVVM Light PCL fork:

[http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/.../GalaSoft.MvvmLight (NET35)/ViewModelBase.cs](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/onovotny/MvvmLightPortable/changeset/view/f356af74426f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/ViewModelBase.cs)

[http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/.../GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Helpers/DesignerPlatformLibrary.cs](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/onovotny/MvvmLightPortable/changeset/view/f356af74426f#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Portable/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Helpers/DesignerPlatformLibrary.cs)

Uses Reflection to load up and invoke the appropriate calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should really include this code directly inside the PCL. The roadmap for pcl's looks good - but I doubt FrameworkElement will be portable any time soon.

Either:

- remove this design time code,
- or abstract this code out so that its called via a platform specific interface. See platform abstraction technique on msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx#abstraction
- or use the reflection technique from @Oren's answer

Comment: In my opinion this is one of the few cases where it's probably OK to call platform-specific code from a PCL using reflection.  You just need to know whether you are running in the designer or not.  Unfortunately this is exposed in different ways for the different variations of the XAML UI stack.  If this is the only thing you need that's platform specific, then it's probably not worth creating platform-specific libraries for each platform and making users reference the extra libraries just to avoid using this type of reflection code in a PCL. /cc @MartinSuchan

Answer (score -1):

You really should not use platform dependent calls in PCL. The purpose of PCL is for sharing code, that is common to all target platforms.
If you have to use some platform specific calls, then use Dependency Injection and IoC to hide the actual implementation and use only interface types in PCL, this should work just fine.